# document.body.appendChild to add, but parentNode.removeChild to remove?

Tags: javascript

I've decided it's time for me to learn javascript in a more formal and less haphazard way than I've used it in the past.

So I went to developer.mozilla.org to take their tutorial.

One of the first teaching exercises they provide is in the article entitled,"A First splash into JavaScript" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash, in which they create a simple number guessing game.

In that game's code, the exercise creates a function called setGameOver which creates a button labeled, "Start New Game".

The code for that button is:

```
document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
```

This is followed by another function called resetGame, in which this button is removed from the page:

```
resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
```

My question is: if the code to add the button is document.body.appendChild, why isn't the code to remove the button something like document.body.removeChild?

And why do we have to use parentNode.removeChild instead?

This is the kind of thing with coding tutorials that drives me nuts. They introduce a new command and they don't explain why. They just say in effect, "This is how you remove the button" and they leave it at that. Ugh!

Comment: you could also use `resetButton.remove()`

Comment: Who says you _have_ to use `parentNode.removeChild` rather than `document.body.removeChild`? Did you try it?

Comment: I didn't try it. I'm trying to understand the tutorial at face value. The tutorial says to use parentNode.removeChild, and I'm trying to understand why the author chose that instead of document.body.removeChild.

Comment: It seems strange that they would switch syntax like that in a *tutorial*, though both of the above are valid equivalents. Choice of which one to use is really just down to personal preference, and I guess the author of the tutorial just chose to randomly mix things up. Keep you on your toes ;)

Comment: second-guessing the author's intentions sounds like a frustrating way to consume a tutorial while you're still learning

Comment: Perhaps, but it's also confusing. I know just barely enough about javascript to understand that there could be the alternative command, but I figure that the author must have had a good reason to introduce the new concept. I can only imagine what it must be like to read that if you're totally unfamiliar with javascript.

On the other hand, maybe he didn't. Maybe he just didn't think about it.

Comment: the author is neither switching syntax nor mixing things up. In this specific situation, `document.body.removeChild` and `resetButton.parentNode.removeChild` happen to be equivalent, but only because `resetButton` happened to be applied to `document.body`. By giving you the latter example as an example of how to remove a node, the author not only taught you about the existence of the `parentNode` attribute but also gave you a repeatable way to remove a node whether or not you have direct access to its parent

Comment: Okay, Hamms, that helps a bit. But is there something about parentNode that is useful for me to know at this stage? I ask because he really doesn't discuss parentNode at all. He just uses it in the sample code.

Comment: it's pretty useful to know exactly what that tutorial taught you; that if you have a node saved as a variable, you can access its parent

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to remove and add an element to the page, this just happens to be the way that the tutorial author chose to demonstrate that. Perhaps their intention was to demonstrate that you can in fact access `document.body` through `resetButton.parentNode`, we will never know.

The main point here is that you can remove the button by accessing it's parent node. In this case, we know for a fact that `document.body` is its parent node (we added the button to that element, so it must be the parent), so in this case `resetButton.parentNode` and `document.body` refer to the same object, and are functionally equivalent.

```
var node1 = document.body;
node1.appendChild(resetButton);
// resetButton is now a child of node1 (and document.body, its the same object)
var node2 = resetButton.parentNode;
// we now know that node2 == node1 so we could do either of the following:
node1.removeChild(resetButton);
// -- or --
node2.removeChild(resetButton);
```

If you have the reference to a specific html node (in this case, `resetButton`) and *don't* know what the parent node is, then using `.parentNode` to find the parent would be the right way to do it. If you *do* know the parent (because you just added it) then it doesn't really matter which way you do it.